# Custom node field type should also support content block; what should I do?

Tags: entities, blocks, 8

I'm using the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module for nodes. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Paragraphs module comes with a new "paragraphs" field type that works like Entity Reference's. Simply add a new paragraphs field on any Content Type you want and choose which Paragraph Types should be available to end-users.

But the type is not in the **add select** on `admin/structure/block/block-content/manage/basic/fields/add-field`.

It would be nice, if this module could offer the `paragraphs` field type also for **Content Blocks** (or other **field type creating modules** their types).

Has someone an idea, what the module maintainer has to do along general lines? I want to ask this as a feature request in the module's [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/paragraphs). But it would be nice if I can give some hint to the maintainer.

Comment: Are you sure this is D8, I don't see paragraphs having a release for Drupal 8 but D7 instead

Comment: first dev is here: https://github.com/LennardWesterveld/paragraphs-d8 they made a huge progress in the last days and the D7 version is nearly reproduced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the code, the module does *not* define a field type. It just defines a widget for entity reference fields.

So, what you need to create instead is an entity reference field that points to paragraphs, and then select the Paragraps widget on "Manage form display".

But that should be exactly the same for nodes as well?

Comment: Oh - you are right - i was really stupid and confused ;)  thanks a lot ...